# How to change the node name in the node pool of GKE Cluster in terraform?

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

is there any way to change the node names in the node pool of GKE cluster that was provisioned with terraform?

Currently, the format of it is the following:

```
gke-proj-k8s-qa-proj-k8s-qa-n-998c055f-g74g
```

I would like to change it to something more meaningful like:

```
proj-k8s-qa-pool-a-1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, if you want to change the node name in k8s, you actually need to remove the node, change the manifest and rejoin it to the cluster.  This is not possible with GKE.

I'd suggest adding a custom label (e.g. short_name) to each node.